# is it possible to change UITableView section title background color

Tags: iphone, uitableview

as title, possible to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section       
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    return [v autorelease];
}
```

This was free-handed so forgive any typos, etc..

UPDATE: This only works for 'grouped' tables. Is your table grouped, or normal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Customize the HeaderInSection using the method in UITableViewDelegate Protocol:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

As it returns a UIView, you can set it to anything you like or just

`[UIView setBackgroundColor:UIColor];`